# MinGW-w64 8.1.0 rev 0 doesn't compile when including <filesystem>

Tags: mingw-w64

2 days ago, I was excited to note that MinGW-w64 released its gcc 8.1.0, revision 0. Unfortunately, a simple program

```
#include <filesystem>
int main() {}
```

does not compile. It results in a bunch of errors inside `<filesystem>`, starting with

```
C:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/fs_path.h: In member function 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path& std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::operator/=(const std::filesystem::__cxx11::path&)':
C:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/fs_path.h:237:47: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' and 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path')
|| (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Who's to blame for that? Or better, to whom is that error to report?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This problem could be due to the gcc distribution (mingw-w64) or to the compiler itself (gcc).

As first, more likely hypothesis I think it could be an issue of the distribution, so I have just added it as a bug to the sourceforge website of mingw-w64.

https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/737/

If they find that's a problem of gcc, this could be readdressed to the compiler website (gcc.gnu.org).

Let's wait and see what they answer on sourceforge.

Marco

Comment: FWIW, 1 year later, I just tried it with a fresh MinGW-w64 install (sporting gcc 8.1...), and still fails. MSYS2's own fresh GCC package, OTOH, which is 9.1.0, compiles and runs cleanly.

Comment: Indeed, installing MinGW via MSYS2 seems to be the fix. As of 04/2021, it provides GCC 10.2, while mingw-w64 hasn't been updated beyond 8.x.

Answer (score 7):

So, I am going to give you the full proof solution for this similar error which also comes when someone tries to use the STL header file which is #include<bits/stdc++.h>

So, this error is occurring because you are currently using the GCC version 8.2.0 which is the default on the MinGW website.
To solve this problem you need to update to GCC 10.2.0

Following are the steps you need to follow:-
1.) Download and install the Msys2 from https://www.msys2.org/
2.) Run or launch this and type pacman -Syu and hit enter then it will ask you to continue by typing Y/N just type enter without pressing Y/n.
3.) Close this and again launch msys2 at least run this command 2-3 times until it shows nothing to do with or nothing to update.
4.) For doing the same I am also sharing a link to the youtube video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXF4A5UeSeM&

5.) For checking that you have successfully installed GCC 10.2.0 just open cmd and type GCC --version and hit enter if it is showing 10.2.0 hurray u did it, wait this is not the end.
6.) Now uninstall Clion or any IDE which you are using.
7.) Before reinstalling it you need to delete some of the remaining Jetbrains dump files which are showing in your program files folder (name Jetbrains) Delete that folder and  Reinstall it.
8.) Now select Msys2/MingW-64, not the previous one which you have in your system already (normal MinGW) while installing it.
9.) Now You can go to your add or remove program section and can delete that waste normal MinGW-64, not the msys2 (don't delete msys2) only delete ming64 the previous one.
10.) Now you can enjoy running that sexy stl library without having any error.

Still, you have any problem doing these steps just ask me in the comment.
Thanks, Guys.

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem between c++17 and file system, perhaps this link will help.
[issue regarding MinGW-w64 8.1.0 compile issue](https://github.com/mxe/mxe/issues/2220)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)