# Build gcc on Windows with another gcc version

Tags: c++, gcc, build, mingw-w64

How to compile the newest gcc release under Windows 10? I have the latest `mingw-w64`[available here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/) which isn't fully `c++17` compliant (I cannot use the `filesystem` library). A build called `winlibs` is also available but it is built on `mingw-w64` 8.0.0, so newer standards aren't fully supported. I downloaded the compressed file `gcc-10.3.0.tar.gz`.
What are the steps needed to do build any new (or old) gcc release on Windows natively without resorting to `cygwin` or `msys` or `wsl`?

Comment: "I cannot use the filesystem library"  Why not?  You should be able to.

Comment: No, it is not possible to do it with the available mingw-64 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50546025/mingw-w64-8-1-0-rev-0-doesnt-compile-when-including-filesystem

Comment: I do it all the time!  What happens when you try?

Comment: Something similar to this https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/737/

Comment: *"built on mingw-w64 8.0.0, so newer standards aren't fully supported"* What standards exactly? Note that MinGW 8.0.0 is not the same thing as GCC 8.0.0.

Comment: For instance C++17 and C++20

Comment: If you look at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), GCC 10.3 (which is what winlibs ships) implements most of C++17 and C++20 features. You sure you need something more recent than 10.3?

Comment: That's why I need to build it

Comment: What GCC version are you trying to build?

Comment: The latest one, but I am asking how to do it in general?

Comment: There is currently no way to build gcc on Windows without cygwin/msys/wsl.

Answer (score 1):

Building GCC isn't trivial. It involves multiple steps, starting with having all the dependancies available.

You already had an older winlibs release, who don't you just get the latest winlibs build from http://winlibs.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what problem you are having with std::filesystem.  Perhaps you are using a different mingw.  Here is how I get mingw64

> Download and install the latest g++ 64 bit compiler from
> http://www.msys2.org/ Follow installation instructions on that page.
> Note that you will have to stop and restart the MSYS2 command line
> tool several times. To do this, close the window and then run
> C:\msys64\msys2_shell. When pacman ( packet manager ) reports "there
> is nothing to do" run it once more with the command pacman -S
> mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain

Comment: All right, but I need to build it from source any idea without going any Unix like sytem.

Comment: He is asking about building it with msys2